# jquery fade effect on 5 images on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

is there any jquery or any script, that when u click on one link, few images on a page change?

Comment: I would say yes, yes there are.  What have you tried so far that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Just give each image a class 'changingimage'.

```
$('img.changingimage').hide();
$('a#clickme').click(function(){
    $('img.changingimage').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript use function `setInterval()`
You should take a look at [Javascript animation](http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation), best tutorial for me.